# Angular animation :leave not triggered

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have a tooltip component with animations in which the `:enter` animation is working as expected but the `:leave` animation never triggered.

Here is a link to stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/building-tooltip-eoby9e?file=src/app/tooltip/tooltip.component.ts

```
  animations: [
    trigger('tooltip', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ opacity: 0 }),
        animate(300, style({ opacity: 1 })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate(300, style({ opacity: 0 })),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
```

Another example with `@HostBinding`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dialog',
  template: '<ng-container cdkPortalOutlet></ng-container>',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  animations: [
    trigger('dialog', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({
          opacity: 0,
          transform: 'translateY(-100%)'
        }),
        animate('400ms ease-out',
          style({
            opacity: 1,
            transform: 'translateY(0)'
          }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('400ms ease-out',
          style({
            opacity: 0,
            transform: 'translateY(-100%)'
          }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class DialogComponent extends BasePortalOutlet implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  @ViewChild(CdkPortalOutlet) portalOutlet: CdkPortalOutlet;
  @HostBinding('@dialog') dialog = true;
```

Answer (score 3):

that is a tricky case. the component that is appearing/disappiring is `AwesomeTooltipComponent` while in your example animation is attached to its child and therefore parent disappears instantly. I fixed that by applying animation to `AwesomeTooltipComponent` with the help of `HostBinding` rather than its child div.
check it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/building-tooltip-h4pxnf?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip%2Ftooltip.component.ts

Comment: It worked indeed. Though I have another case where I do have a @HostBinding which extends BasePortalOutlet and the animation doesn't works there. Question updated.

Comment: could  you please update the stackblitz to reproduce that?

Comment: I see the old example by the link

Comment: Try to click the button

Comment: This is a really slick way of doing it